# What does the "source-like" symbol mean in the first NMOS of the CMOS NAND gate?

Tags: mosfet, cmos, symbol, nand, bootstrap

I would assume that it means the source is not left floating if Q4 is off
(boot-strapping ?).

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the bodies of the devices? Those are tied to ground to avoid floating body effect. Just as PMOS are tied high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the "body" (or "bulk") connection for the MOSFET. As Wikipedia explains:

> The *bulk* or *body* connection, if shown, is shown connected to the back of the channel with an arrow indicating pMOS or nMOS. Arrows always point from P to N, so an NMOS (N-channel in P-well or P-substrate) has the arrow pointing in (from the bulk to the channel). If the bulk is connected to the source (as is generally the case with discrete devices) it is sometimes angled to meet up with the source leaving the transistor. If the bulk is not shown (as is often the case in IC design as they are generally common bulk) an inversion symbol is sometimes used to indicate PMOS, alternatively an arrow on the source may be used in the same way as for bipolar transistors (out for nMOS, in for pMOS).
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET#Circuit_symbols

The body is typically (but not always) connected to the source (as in the NAND gate you show) and is often omitted from the schematic if that is the case. Many discrete MOSFETs have the body internally tied to the source so that the MOSFET is packaged as a three pin device even though it really has four terminals:

[image: MOSFET structure]

<sub>Source: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a5/MOSFET_Structure.png</sub>

The body affects the MOSFET's parameters (e.g., [threshold voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/131598/51760)) if not connected to the source.